# Cannot resolve module for webpack dev server using development config

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using the (now-deprecated) [CodingZeal react boilerplate repo](https://github.com/CodingZeal/react-boilerplate) as a base for a project and am running into an error.

I've cloned the repo to test with and (with the commit as of 4/1/2016 checked out: 406662f) can run that just fine and see the `public/client.js` file generated.

However, in my project I get `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'webpack-dev-server/app'` when I run `webpack-dev-server`.

This is due to `/webpack/development.js` where I have the following:

```
config.entry.app.unshift(
  'webpack-dev-server/app?http://localhost:8080',
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'
)
```

It doesn't seem to like that first line.

In `/webpack/base.js` that is required in `development.js` I have:

```
...
entry: {
  app: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../global.js'), path.resolve(__dirname, '../app.js')]
},
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
  filename: 'bundle.js'
}
...
```

The `/public` directory exists, but no file ever shows up there.

Note that in the reference repo, their main folder is `/client`, where I've decided to call mine `/app`.  I think this is arbitrary and shouldn't affect anything.  I took care to update all instances of `client` to `app` in my project.

Thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I took care to update all instances of client to app in my project.

You are correct, except that you replaced an instance of `client` that wasn't referring to your files. `webpack-dev-server/client` refers to the module [client](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/tree/master/client) inside `webpack-dev-server`. Changing it back should solve your issue:

```
config.entry.app.unshift(
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'
)
```

Comment: ah.  I was wondering what this module could be that had to do with what I'd named my directory but had never installed :)